# Bootscan after virus find without log files update?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, avast

During a quick search avast found and removed a virus on my PC (Win32:Ramnit-DO).
After that it I updated the software (today an update came out) and it wanted to do a reboot to make a bootscan which I accepted.

The scan itself took almost 3h to complete. During this I saw the usual outputs (nothing that indicated a virus). But as I have not seen the whole output I tried to look for the logs and thus looked in the folder:

C:\ProgramData\AVAST Software\Persistent Data\Avast

And there under logs and under reports. 
Even though I saw logfiles there including aswBoot.txt under reports I did not find any CURRENT logfile. The only current ones being: AvastSvc.log, AvastUI.log and GrimeFighter.log (but nothing shows even the found virus during the quick search.....I only see it when I look into the virus container in the avast menu).

Now my question here is: IS that normal? Or is that something I should be cautious when it happens (aka a behaviour that could point to a virus infection that has affected avast itself already)? Or where do I find the log files I need (aka the bootfile logfiles)

*As a note here: As the infected file was an old .dll from a bought program from 3 years back and no further infection was found I'm guessing that it was a wrong alarm from avast but one can't be cautious enough sadly.*

Comment: which version of avast you are using? , In some version  it should be in ‘Scan’ » ‘Scan history’.

Comment: Do you mean the cost free, non cost free versions? (if so the cost free one) or what do you mean with versoin?

Comment: Check C:\ProgramData\Avast Software\Avast\report\aswBoot.txt.
Also show hidden files and extensions.

Comment: I saw the file there (I always show hidden files and extensions, but the last change date and also the last date mentioned inseide the file was 1 year ago (and not as I had expected 3 mins earlier as the boot check was 3 mins earlier).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen such "wrong alarms" many times in Avast and Kaspersky after removing a virus.
Remove it manually from inside the program or clear all logs.
Sometimes they don't get removed, but in my case they disappear after some days.

Here are pathes of [Avast log files](https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=86669.0) and [how to clear logs](http://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/clear-old-avast-logs-22750.html).
To recover after Win32/Ramnit malware [follow these steps](http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/entry.aspx?Name=Win32/Ramnit) (provided by Microsoft).

Also check autoruns using [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx), and check extensions of your browser (in browser settings), because Ramnit steals bank user names and passwords and it can use extensions to achieve it.

Anyway, I would recommend you to scan computer using a good antivirus (such as Kaspersky IS, Norton Security etc, and not that free ones), even a trial version will do the work.